# Can't configure postgres on local machine to work with rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, installation, rails-postgresql

I have an existing rails application. My database and application seem to work fine on the remote database (I made changes on my local machine but am still connected to the remote database), but I cannot seem to be able to configure the database on my local machine.

I am trying to find out which PostgreSQL I'm running on my Machine. There is the one pre-installed on my Mac 10.7.5 I believe, and there is one I've recently installed with Homebrew.

I ran `which psql` and got the one pre-installed on my machine: `/usr/bin/psql` 
I tried changing the PATH in the `~/.bash_profile` but that didn't change anything.

When I run `ps -ef | grep postgres` I get:

```
  502  5775   123   0  9:05AM ??         0:00.03 /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres -r /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
  502  5777  5775   0  9:05AM ??         0:00.00 postgres: checkpointer process       
  502  5778  5775   0  9:05AM ??         0:00.03 postgres: writer process       
  502  5779  5775   0  9:05AM ??         0:00.03 postgres: wal writer process       
  502  5780  5775   0  9:05AM ??         0:00.03 postgres: autovacuum launcher process       
  502  5781  5775   0  9:05AM ??         0:00.05 postgres: stats collector process       
  502  5956  5852   0  9:28AM ttys000    0:00.00 grep postgres
```

But when I run `psql appname` I get:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I'm not sure which database is being used currently on my machine (sqlite may be the default), and which version of postgres (preinstalled or homebrew). How do I change this and get it to work.
Also, how do I get it to work with my application. 
Also, I am editing the database.yml file (which currently has the remote server) to my localhost but I don't know what to use under `username`, anything I try (i.e. `postgres`, `root`, `mymacusername`) I am told `doesn't exist`.

Comment: I think for postrge SQL the default user is postgres, try also add to you database.yml file, into to the development section line host: localhost.

Comment: I added that already, not sure what I did (I made many changes) to make it work, but now it's working...